# Mouse Acceleration in Deus Ex: Human Revolution

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

Is there a way to enable **non-linear mouse acceleration** in **Deus Ex: Human Revolution**?

I'm asking about a non-linear translation of physical mouse movement speed to angular speed of the in-game view. This type of translation feels very natural to me, as it's implemented in many desktop operating systems and in most FPS games I've played.

I don't know if *acceleration* is the right term for this, but I remember Windows' mouse control panel calling it that way in some older versions of Windows. In Window 7 it's called *enhance pointer precision* and is enabled by default. It's called *pointer ballistics* by Microsoft and is described [in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463319.aspx).

I can't find any option controlling this in the game's menu or it's setup utility (launched from Steam by choosing *Setup Deus Ex: Human Revolution* after double clicking the game in the game library). Without this option, I find aiming very hard because if I configure the mouse sensitivity to get acceptable aiming precision, making a 180-degree-turn is impossible without either moving my wrist or lifting the mouse and moving it in the reverse direction.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and admit I don't fully understand your question, but I do know that toggling VSync (can't remember if I had to turn it on or off) fixed mouse acceleration problems for me in that game.

Comment: What about just increasing the mouse sensitivity?  If you have a high resolution mouse, (mine is 5000 dpi max, but I keep it around 2500) you can easily whip around without having to lift and track.

Comment: [Some players](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2074758) consider that cripple mouse movement simply because the PC version is a port from the console version.

Comment: @Sterno What part of my question is unclear? I will try to improve it!

Comment: @NickT A more precise mouse would probably do some good, but my main problem is that I'm not used to such precise mouse movement (I'm more of a casual gamer) and that I'm very accustomed to the behavior of other games.

Comment: I've tinkered with mouse sensitivity settings and setting them too high results in another problem: My eyes have a hard time following the jerky motion that results from small mouse movements. I will need to see how much I can adapt after a few hours of gameplay …

Comment: @Feuermurmel Sorry, it's not that your question is particularly unclear, it's just that I don't know much about mouse acceleration and what you mean by "non-linear translation". I just thought I'd leave a quick note about what fixed the weird feel of the mouse acceleration to me in that game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does indeed seem to be impossible to have any kind of nonlinear acceleration in *Deus Ex: Human Revolution*. Yet I was surprised how well I could adjust to the difference in conversion from mouse to camera movement between this game and what I'm used to from other games (using any of the games based on the Source engine from Valve as a reference).

But I still notice that I need to move the mouse much farther and/or faster while being less precise at targeting, so I still consider this a deficiency of *Deus Ex: Human Revolution*'s engine.